# Constructor in C - Declare (in .h) and define (in .c) It does not behave as expected

Tags: c, constructor

I declare a constructor in `constructor.h` and define it in `constructor.c`.
I will show both files:

`constructor.h`

```
void begin(void) __attribute__((constructor));
```

`constructor.c`

```
void begin(void) {
    printf("INIT");
}
```

My main.c, which has code which uses the function, is including constructor.h.

Previously I defined and declared `begin` in the same .h file and that worked fine.
Now I try to separate code, declare in .h and define in .c, and it is not working anymore.

Why could that be?

Comment: Do you include .h in .c?

Comment: No, i will try this

Comment: there is not very much sense to export `begin()`. Just make it `static` and keep it only in the `.c` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the compiler be aware of the content of the header while compiling the .c file, you need to include the header in the code file.

```
#include "constructor.h"

/* ... */
```

Also you should implement the function as declared:

```
/* ... */

void begin(void) __attribute__((constructor)) {
    printf("INIT");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It solves the problem. In 10 minuts I will Check as Accepted Answer. Is any way to avoid include in all .c files the .h files? (doing them exters, or something like that? do you know?) Thank you

Comment: Not including the corresponding headers in the code files is not a good idea. Just get used to it. It allows the compiler to tell you when you failed to keep implementation and declaration consistent, which you definitly will appreciate more with more experience, not less.

Comment: I said it because I have a file called functionPrototypes.h and then, I would have to include it in all .c files (actually, constructor.h is a subpart of functionPrototypes.h)

Comment: You do not want a single header with all prototypes and declarations for a lot of code files either. At least not in a large project. Making nice pairs is the thing. Write some functions which do something meaningful in one file, put their "API" prototypes in an accompanying header. Include the headers which provide the API you need in a code file, all of them, directly, none of those you do not need.

Comment: So, would I have to restructure my project? I have a .h with about 20 function declarations, and then 20 .c files with each of its definitions, which I use in the program as appropriate

Comment: Not have to. It is a question of opinion, sometimes of company-established rules. Asking about it would be off-topic here, by the way. But allow me to speculate that most readers here would recommend to restructure as soon as anybody else starts helping with your project. Or now.